# How to use global variables in Vue.js templates?

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to use language component, described here
https://github.com/Haixing-Hu/vue-i18n

But I don't know, how to use it without mistakes.
I added components

```
var i18n = require('vue-i18n');

// set plugin
Vue.use(i18n, {
  baseUrl: 'resources/i18n'
});
```

in main.js file and then tried to use variables, like $i18n.message.hello
in my template (vue files, which was used as components in router).

My components' syntax is like

```
<template>
<div id="myid">
{{like $i18n.message.hello}}
</div>
</template>

export default {
  data () {
    return {
    ...
```

And when I run code, I don't see what I need and in console there are error messages, like

***Property or method "$i18n" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render***

So how I need to set this variable, so I can use it.
Same proplem appears with "store" variable

Comment: Use a better library: https://github.com/kazupon/vue-i18n

Comment: Library is not a problem, problem is that I can't use any of variable beggining with "$"

Comment: You need first call the `$setLanguage` method to able use `$i18n`

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](http://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/started.html#html), you have to use the built-in function `$t()` which takes a string as a parameter, that is also the path of your translation value.

For example, if in your translations file you have the following object:

```js
const messages = {
  en: {
    message: {
      hello: 'hello world'
    }
  },
  ja: {
    message: {
      hello: 'こんにちは、世界'
    }
  }
}

// With this config

const i18n = new VueI18n({
  locale: 'ja', // set locale
  messages, // set locale messages
})


// Create a Vue instance with `i18n` option
new Vue({
  i18n // This is not Vue.use, it is inserted like the store
}).$mount('#app')
```

Then in your html it should look like something like that:

```html
<h1>{{ $('message.hello' }}</h1>
```